# How to integrate latitude/longitude into a dataset and display it on map

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, ckan

I am new with CKAN but I got some experience and I can add some customized fields into a dataset.

We are going to use a dataset to record either publication but some measurements as well. A resource will be some file of measurements.

We want to be able to geolocate the place where measurements have been made.

It's the reason why I installed ckanext-geospacial.

The goal is to be able to have aditional field in a dataset or resource to save, at least, latitude, longitude, altitude.

We also would like to have a map (as google map or something else...), with a marker of the measurement place.

First, I am not sure if I choose the right ckan extension. Does ckanext-spatial will help me?

In any case, I would appreciate your help

1. **to choose the best extension for my need**
2. **to setup ckanext-spatial.**

I installed ckanext-spatial and I got the following warming messages, while I test the installation:

```
user@pc:/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-spatial$ sudo -u postgres psql -d ckan_default -c "SELECT postgis_full_version()"
NOTICE:  Function postgis_gdal_version() not found.  Is raster support enabled and rtpostgis.sql installed?
NOTICE:  Function postgis_topology_scripts_installed() not found. Is topology support enabled and topology.sql installed?
NOTICE:  Function postgis_raster_scripts_installed() not found. Is raster support enabled and rtpostgis.sql installed?
NOTICE:  Function postgis_raster_lib_version() not found. Is raster support enabled and rtpostgis.sql installed?
```

What should I do?

Second question; how can I use the ckanext-spatial within a dataset? How can I use it to display location?

Comment: I tried answering the first question (_choose the best extension for my need_). If you _really_ need ckanext-spatial, I think it would be best to write a new question detailing your installation problems.

Answer (score 0):

In order to view geolocalized data as markers on a map you just need the [**Data Explorer** plugin](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/data-viewer.html#data-explorer), which includes a *Map View* (I think CKAN's installation already includes this plugin).

As a prerequisite for the Data Explorer plugin to work, you also need the [**DataStore** extension](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html), which saves the rows of the `.csv` resources as records in a database, such allowing more efficient access to the data.

Once you have the data in the DataStore and the DataExplorer's `recline_view`  added to the `ckan.plugins` line in CKAN's configuration file, you will be able to use the *Map View* to select the fields storing the latitude and longitude values and see the markers on the map (if your resources have two fields named `latitude` and `longitude`, or `lat` and `lon`, they will be automatically detected and used as coordinates).

If I understand correctly, the [ckanext-spatial](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-spatial) plugins provides *spatial queries*, so if you just want a map with markers you don't need it.

Comment: Thank a lot for your answer. I am going to investigateur on your suggest. I am sorry for my question but I am new with CKAN. What's the différence with a plugin and a extension and the installation of a plugin (data explorer) is the same way of an extension? By the way I am going to look the doc, for sure

Comment: That's nice, I could have a good result. I could create a resource with curl. I also observed that a resource has now a 'Data explorer' tab and below, three other tables. The last is 'Map'. When I click on Map it show me a MapQuest map. Is there a way to change it with OpenStreetMap? Thank a lot, you help me a lot

Comment: The map source _should_ now be customizable in the configuration (see http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/data-viewer.html#datastore-map for an example); otherwise, you can directly change the map url in the source code, as in [this pull request](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/pull/3174)